# laravel validate only if another value present

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to validate a field only if another field is present.

This is my current implementation that can illustrate what I want to do. 
*I need to perform unique validation on **campaign_lead_id** only if **campaign_id** is present. Other wise, there will be query exception thrown because `$params['campaign_id']` is empty.*

```
    $params = [
        'campaign_id' => '',
        'campaign_lead_id' => '23'
    ];

    $customCampaignLeadRule = (empty($params['campaign_id'])
        ? ''
        : '|unique:leads,campaign_lead_id,null,id,campaign_id,' . $params['campaign_id']
    );

    $rules = [
        'campaign_id' => 'required',
        'campaign_lead_id' => 'bail|required' . $customCampaignLeadRule,
    ];

    $validator = $this->validator->make($params, $rules);
```

P.S. I am aware of `bail` and `required_if`. What I need is not `required_if` because I always require `campaign_lead_id` not only when other field is required. My implementation works for me but I think it is not the most correct way.

Comment: why not put `$params['campaign_id']` as ternary like `$campaign_id = empty($params['campaign_id']) ? ' ' : $params['campaign_id']`, and use `$campaign_id` inside $rules ?

Comment: It willl still not work because `campaign_id` field is integer and passing blank `'  '` will throw query exception

Comment: Another way is to add `campaign_lead_id` in `$rules` after checking condition like `if(!empty($params['compaign_id'])){ $rules['campaign_lead_id'] = 'bail|required | unique:leads,campaign_lead_id,null,id,campaign_id,' . $params['campaign_id']' }`

Comment: if this is not resolved yet, then you can use `'campaign_lead_id' => 'sometimes|bail|required'`  .. sometimes will help only to validate if filed has some value and that is optional on your FrontEnd